# Readability vs. Maintainability: Condensing statements to loops

Tags: c, performance, winapi, readability, maintainability

Firstly, an example of what I'm referring to:

```
UINT f, i, s;
CONST UINT k[5] = { VK_LBUTTON, VK_RBUTTON, VK_MBUTTON, VK_XBUTTON1, VK_XBUTTON2 };

for (f = RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN, i = 0, s = RI_KEY_MAKE; f != RI_MOUSE_WHEEL; f <<= 1, i += s, s = !s)
    if ((pMouseData->usButtonFlags & f) == f)
        SetVKeyState(k[i], s);
```

Compared to this:

```
if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN)
    SetVKeyState(VK_LBUTTON, RI_KEY_MAKE);

if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_UP)
    SetVKeyState(VK_LBUTTON, RI_KEY_BREAK);

if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_RIGHT_BUTTON_DOWN)
    SetVKeyState(VK_RBUTTON, RI_KEY_MAKE);

if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_RIGHT_BUTTON_UP)
    SetVKeyState(VK_RBUTTON, RI_KEY_BREAK);

if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_MIDDLE_BUTTON_DOWN)
    SetVKeyState(VK_MBUTTON, RI_KEY_MAKE);

if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_MIDDLE_BUTTON_UP)
    SetVKeyState(VK_MBUTTON, RI_KEY_BREAK);

if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_X1_BUTTON_DOWN)
    SetVKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1, RI_KEY_MAKE);

if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_X1_BUTTON_UP)
    SetVKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1, RI_KEY_BREAK);

if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_X2_BUTTON_DOWN)
    SetVKeyState(VK_XBUTTON2, RI_KEY_MAKE);

if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_X2_BUTTON_UP)
    SetVKeyState(VK_XBUTTON2, RI_KEY_BREAK);
```

The later code is obviously a completely unrolled loop.

This is really a question over whether *readability* or *reducing redundancy* (as in repeated statements in different areas of the code) is better in the long run.

I'm more concerned about visiting it later in the context of a large code-base. Surely reducing the number of areas to modify is a good thing; does it matter the initialisation and update statements for the `for` loop are a little messy?

Has anyone experience in this, probably trivial, issue.

Comment: Post code here. Do not send us to elsewhere.

Comment: if you want readability you can start by renaming your variables

Comment: No, I mean __readability__. The unrolled loop is easily read because it's explicit and doesn't use things like comma tricks to use multiple statements in a small space but open to errors if the statement needs to be changed because there's so many to changed.

I realise my names aren't amazing; they weren't meant to be the focus. It was the idea of pushing several variables into a loop in order to condense the unrolled version.

Comment: Quick glance - the unrolled line-by-line code is immediately understandable, easily modified and simply debugged.  That's enough  for me.  I do a lot of maintenance/enhancement and 'clever' code that takes effort to unravel just makes me want to strangle the moron that wrote it.

Comment: @MartinJames Sorry, can't +2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to condense only statements that are completely alike:

```
const UINT k[5] = { VK_LBUTTON, VK_RBUTTON, VK_MBUTTON, VK_XBUTTON1, VK_XBUTTON2 };

static_assert( (RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN << 2) == RI_MOUSE_RIGHT_BUTTON_DOWN );

for ( UINT i = 0; i < _count_of(k); ++i ) {
    if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & (RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN << 2*i))
        SetVKeyState(k[i], RI_KEY_MAKE); 
    if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & (RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_UP << 2*i)))
        SetVKeyState(k[i], RI_KEY_BREAK); 
}
```

All the comma operators are gone, unusual loop increment is gone, symbolic variables are still used for the key state.

I think this is actually easier to read than the original, because it fits on one page of code, and the repetition is obvious.

EDIT: And now the flag-relation assumption is documented.

I might actually go as far as:

```
struct { UINT vk;      UINT downflag;                 UINT upflag;
} const k[] = {
       { VK_LBUTTON,   RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN,     RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_UP },
       { VK_RBUTTON,   RI_MOUSE_RIGHT_BUTTON_DOWN,    RI_MOUSE_RIGHT_BUTTON_UP },
    ...
};
for ( UINT i = 0; i < _count_of(k); ++i ) {
    if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & k[i].downflag)
        SetVKeyState(k[i].vk, RI_KEY_MAKE); 
    if (pMouseData->usButtonFlags & k[i].upflag)
        SetVKeyState(k[i].vk, RI_KEY_BREAK); 
}
```

in order to remove the assumption about the flags using adjacent bits in the correct order.

You *could* use the latter version making the second argument to `SetVKeyState` one of the table columns, but IMO that loses the valuable pairing structure.

Comment: The statement "The key is to condense only statements that are completely alike" seems really obvious in hindsight but it really clear my confusion.

Comment: @Alex: In the code you provided, clearly there's a pattern of paired statements.  So the loop version should try to preserve that pattern.